# Publish Prerecorded (or live) Video, instead of Camera in Flash/Flex/Air via RTMP to FMS

Tags: flash, video, stream, rtmp, flash-media-server

I'm looking for a way to stream video from the desktop to an FMS installation. I know that in ActionScript, it's possible to do:

```
netStream.attachCamera(camera);
netStream.attachAudio(mic);
```

but not:

```
netStream.attachVideo(file);
```

Is there another way to get by this *without* using FMLE?

I have also tried creating a NativeProcess with Flazr (gives me an error) and ffmpeg (not reliable for streaming via rtmp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`NetStream.appendBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29) to pass a video loaded with [`URLStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) as a [`ByteArray`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html)